# Should I ask for a clarification in reply mail?

Tags: professionalism, mistakes

[image: Grammar Mistake]

Recently I got this mail from my colleague, Should I ask for a clarification through reply mail? or should i say in personal?

Comment: Regardless of whether it's appropriate to do, I have to argue the point that while your English is perfectly understandable, you don't seem experienced enough with the language to correct someone else's mistakes. You can only really do that if you're absolutely sure that you're right and if you've shown in the past that your grasp of the language is much better than the person you're correcting.

Comment: The curse of the grammer nazi: If you make any corrections to someone's spelling or grammar, you can be sure that there will be some even more embarassing mistake in your correction.

Comment: The question has been edited to improve the grammar. Normally, I would consider that a good edit, but in this case the OP's level of English writing is relevant information.

Comment: I think what you're asking is how to fix vague questions that contain incorrect grammar? If you truly cannot understand the other party reply and say, "Can you please elaborate on what you require?" Don't reply, "Ur grammer is horrible. i can't under you're writng" will make you look even sillier.

Comment: I have rolled it back the grammar edit. To the OP: You and your colleagues could spend a lot of time criticizing each others' grammar and spelling. Is that the best way to spend your working time?

Comment: Are all these files belong to us?

Comment: Sorry i edited the question

Answer (score 14):

If you don't understand it then ask for clarification by return email. But there is no need to correct them unless:-

a) you have a company policy in place that emails must be in correct English

b) the email is ambiguous in meaning and you correct their grammar and ask them if your interpretation is correct.

c) there is an understanding between you that you will help them with their English

Comment: It might be worth mentioning if you think the chain might reach a client. I.e. If they're asking you to confirm something and you suspect they might forward your reply in some way.

Comment: I don't see why, someone else's grammar is not my problem, so long as my own part of the chain is fine. I would think it would look worse if the client is reading nitpicking over grammar, particularly if the OP's English is of the quality it was pre-edit

Comment: I don't think it would fall back on you so yes it's not 'your problem'. Your reply suggested an exhaustive list of general situations you would want to correct a colleague. I'm suggesting that for some people that appearing professional to clients/customers is important and correcting them is appropriate.

Comment: Hence the a) option, a Company Policy

Comment: I don't really think that covers it. I've never seen an email policy that says 'You must check all incoming emails for grammatical errors and issue a correction'. It's about what is professional and what is pedantry.

Comment: +1 for your input, we have those company policies here in many places, because, although we're all bilingual, some are more bilingual than others and professional communications are usually in English. To the point that in many companies all employee mails are vetted if they're potentially client facing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31097/discussion-between-kilisi-and-dustybin80).

Comment: Fair enough point +1

Answer (score 6):

Being the grandson of an English teacher, the grammar mistakes of others scream at me from the page or screen.

However, there are only two circumstances I can think of where it would be appropriate to correct grammar in this situation:

1. The communication is going to be distributed to customers or industry publications, and the poor language usage would be embarrassing to the company or detract from the perceived authority/competence of the content.
2. The mistakes are so egregious that it leaves the meaning of the message vague or indiscernible.

There is some value in helping a junior employee improve their communications overall, but calling out specific failings will (usually) not be productive.

Comment: +1 and even if the meaning is vague, it's more constructive to ask for clarification of the meaning than to correct the grammar.

Comment: @ColleenV - You're right, but I was looking at it from the point-of-view of supervising an employee's communication with others, rather than one-to-one.

Answer (score 2):

What is there to gain by correcting the grammatical mistake of your colleague?

Is this colleague an equal or senior or junior to you? I would not mention it and should the items you consider to be errors continue to happen, then I would say something in person. This depends on the type of mistake (spelling? punctuation? incorrect phrase used?) and if this person also emails clients/external people

Answer (score 0):

If it's correspondence between the two of you, **leave it alone**.  You're not being paid to be a language teacher, and you will cause a rift with your colleague and will start to be viewed as rather self-righteous.

If it's a document that you are creating in collaboration with another colleague, then that's an entirely different case.  You want such a document to be cohesive, but in the end you have to examine the tradeoff of try to make it perfect vs getting it *done*.